# $a = a \iff b = b, \forall b, b \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, logic

Now it is the fact of the matter that $=$ is reflexive.

However, if there existed a $b: b \neq b,  b \in \mathbb{N}$ would that mean that $\not\exists a: a = a, a \in \mathbb{N}$? I.e on the set of Natural numbers is the equality relation either reflexive or irreflexive?

Can we infer that $b = b$ given that $a = a$? Can we infer that $a = a$ given that $b = b$?

To clarify: I got into a debate 
 with some people who believe you should never assign a probability of 1 to any (including mathematical) statements. I was trying to prove that assigning a probability of less than 1 to for example "$a = a$" would lead to absurd results. I just wanted to confirm if the equality relation was either (logical xor) reflexive or irreflexive (this is necessary for my proof).

Comment: You are not clear about wuantification. In general $\forall b,\Phi(b)$ and $\forall a,\Phi(a)$ are equivalent. It may also depend on what you mean by $=$ in the first place, if not a relation tha by definition has this property

Comment: It is a relation that by definition is equivalent.

Comment: Axiom of first-order logic with equality: $\forall x (x=x)$. Thus, by instantiation, we get: $a=a$ as well as $b=b$, for every *terms* $a,b$.

Comment: Formally, this means that in every first-order theory we may prove e.g. $\vdash b=b$ (for any term $b$).Thus, by *weakening* (adding un-necessary assumptions): $a=a \vdash b=b$ and thus, by *Deduction Th*: $\vdash a=a \to b=b$. In the same way: $\vdash b=b \to a=a$.

Comment: Do you mean b = b & for all b, b in N or do you mean for all b in N, b = b?

Comment: $\forall b \in N, b = b$.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you somehow redefine $=$, $a=a$ is true for any $a$.

Thus, $(\exists b)\,b\neq b$ is always false. [From a false statement, you can derive anything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion), so in particular, you can prove that $(\forall a)\, a\neq a$.

By the same token, for any $a,b$, the statement $a=a\iff b=b$ is always true, by definition of $\iff$ (which is true if both statements are true), much like $1+1<3\iff n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$.